# How to compare two tables having record type column in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-science, data-warehouse

I have two nested tables one is source and another is target table. I wanted to compare nested columns of source and target table. I am comparing two tables to check weather data is being updated in source table or not. Is there any sql in BigQuery to achieve the same?

[image]

Here are my approaches which I was previously doing to compare two tables with nested record:

**1. This is the first approach:**

```
SELECT to_json_string(info) FROM database.nested_table_source
except distinct
SELECT to_json_string(info) FROM nested_table_target
```

to_json_string() is not working, since this function returns different sequence of source rows and target rows sometimes, even though data is same in both tables, it results out different records.

**2. This is the second approach:**

```
select name
from dataset.nested_table_source a
join dataset.nested_table_target b
using(name)
where
a.name!=b.name  and
(select string_agg(format('%t', s) order by key) from a.info s) 
!= (select string_agg(format('%t', s) order by key ) from b.info s)
```

In this approach I am using string_agg function to compare two nested records. But I am not sure if that is the correct way to compare record fields.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: I don't know other way to do that. But I'm interested if one exists!!

Comment: @guillaume but can you tell weather second approach is correct way to compare two nested tables?

Comment: I find the second approach correct. However, I always have the feeling that building a string and comparing string is absolutely not efficient (in term of performance and speed), but I don't any other solution to that question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach in which you basically stringify an *ordered* set of objects (or the `info` column in your tables), and then compare them against each other.

Here is an example with some dummy data:

```
with source_data as (
    select 
    "VICTOR" as name,
     array[
        struct("A" as key, 3 as value),       
        struct("B" as key, 5 as value)   
    ] as info

    union all 
    
    select 
    "MAX" as name,
     array[
        struct("A" as key, 0 as value),       
        struct("B" as key, 1 as value)   
    ] as info

    union all 
    
    select 
    "SAIF" as name,
     array[
        struct("A" as key, 0 as value),       
        struct("B" as key, 1 as value)   
    ] as info
),
target_data as (
    select 
    "VICTOR" as name,
     array[
        struct("A" as key, 3 as value),       
        struct("B" as key, 15 as value)   
    ] as info

    union all 
    
    select 
    "MAX" as name,
     array[
        struct("A" as key, 0 as value),       
        struct("B" as key, 1 as value)   
    ] as info
)

select name, stringified_source_set as info from (
    select 
        s.name, 
        array_to_string(array(select concat(cast(x.key as string), '|', cast(x.value as string)) from unnest(t.info) as x order by x.key), '|') AS stringified_target_set,
        array_to_string(array(select concat(cast(x.key as string), '|', cast(x.value as string)) from unnest(s.info) as x order by x.key), '|') AS stringified_source_set
    from source_data s
    left join target_data t on t.name = s.name 
)
where (stringified_source_set != stringified_target_set) or (name is null)
```

Note that the above approach does achieve both "horizontal comparison" (i.e. comparing both `info` objects) and "vertical comparison" (i.e. comparing missing entries in the target table which exist in the source table).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. This will work but I have to specify every column like x.key, x.value and so on. If stringified_target_set/stringified_source_set have like 30 columns it would be very tedious process. If there is any other alternatives for that it would be really helpful?